# how do i get a vpc id from another account with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, vpc-peering

I have an existing VPC in a separate account and am creating independent terraforms for more vpc's in new accounts.
I wish to peer specific vpc's within each account but am finding it hard to programatically obtain the vpc_id from the target vpc's. As these vpc's are ephemeral so the vpd_id's will change I want to code this instead of logging into the account to get the vpc_id from the console.

I have tried many variations of data sources and combined with
resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection", resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection_accepter" but so far am failing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you're VPC peering across accounts you need to instantiate [multiple AWS providers](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html#alias-multiple-provider-instances) in Terraform, one for each account. You should then be able to use the `aws_vpc` datasource with the specific provider instance for the peer account to retrieve the VPC id.

The [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/vpc_peering_accepter.html) for `aws_vpc_peering_connection_accepter` shows how to use multiple provider instances. If the peer VPC already exists, rather than create it with Terraform then you should be able to do something like:

```
data "aws_vpc" "peer" {
  provider = "peer"
  # Whatever combination of filters are necessary to locate the VPC, cidr_block, etc.
}
```

You can then refer to `${data.aws_vpc.peer.id}` in your `aws_vpc_peering_connection` resource.